# Customtkinter image issue

Tags: customtkinter

I've got this customtkinter code to place an image on my page:

```
ETH2O_logo = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("ETH2OLogo-100.png"), size = (70, 70))
Logo_image = ctk.CTkLabel(main_info_frame, image=ETH2O_logo)
Logo_image.grid(column = 0, row =0, padx=50)
```

It displays the text "CTkLabel" inside the image.  I can't figure out why.  Can anyone help?  I've imported all the necessary modules and customtkinter works elsewhere in my project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found all I need to do is add 'text = ""' to the CTkLabel definition.